# Can I use srcset attribute in css to edit resolution?

Tags: html, css, srcset

I was wondering if I could somehow use the srcset attribute in css to (for example) make all images 2x, it usually works like this

```
<img src="image.jpg" srcset="image.jpg 1x, higher-resolution-image.jpg 2x" >
```

I wonder if there's a way to use that in css to make all images displayed in 2x
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a srcset equivalent for css background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801745/is-there-a-srcset-equivalent-for-css-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

You should find this post useful:

[Is there a srcset equivalent for css background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801745/is-there-a-srcset-equivalent-for-css-background-image)

It mentions using image-set:

`background: -webkit-image-set( url('path/to/image') 1x, url('path/to/high-res-image') 2x );`

Comment: You should use a flag to point out a duplicate question, rather than linking to the question and duplicating the answer here.

Comment: Good point, but I just thought as the the question was for "all images" that another solution might be needed, perhaps one that would affect all images by default.

Comment: @ShastriH: didn't even use the "share" link ;-). Btw, `-webkit-image-set` can go anywhere an image is asked for, not only `background`, so it should cover all (Webkit) bases.