# Full width responsive background images with srcset and lazy loading

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image-size, srcset

I'm working on a site which has a series of 'hero' panels running down the home page which have text overlaid on large background images.

Ideally I'd like to use inline images with `srcset` and `sizes` so the browser can choose the most appropriate image based on the screen size, rather than just whacking in the largest possible image as a `background-image` and then scaling it down for smaller screens.

So far my markup looks like:

```
<img 
  src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" 
  srcset="/img/trekking_320.jpg 320w,
          /img/trekking_480.jpg 480w,
          /img/trekking_600.jpg 600w,
          /img/trekking_768.jpg 768w,
          /img/trekking_960.jpg 960w" 
  data-sizes="100vw"
  class="lazyload"
>
```

and CSS:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%; width: auto;
}
```

and `overflow:hidden` on the container.

The height of the images is 320px up to 768px, then 480px up to 960px and then a max-height of 600px after that.

I've made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tyssen/full/YQqaoq/) to illustrate the problem. Everything works fine on retina screens at all different screen sizes (mobile, tablet, laptop) and on a normal dpi screen it's fine too up to 768px wide, but after that the images don't fill the screen.

So is it possible to do all the things I've asked in the title? Am I on the right track or do I need to take a completely different approach?

Answer (score 5):

Don't abuse `<img />` for background images - use CSS `background-image` (with `background-size: cover` or `fill` for a 'responsive' look) but use the `image-set` function to specify different images for different device display resolutions:

- [Is there a srcset equivalent for css background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801745/is-there-a-srcset-equivalent-for-css-background-image)
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#image-set-notation

Though as of June 2017, `image-set` is not supported by Firefox/Gecko, Internet Explorer or Edge - only WebKit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera): http://caniuse.com/css-image-set/embed

```
body {
    background-image: -webkit-image-set(
        url('path/to/image') 1x,
        url('path/to/high-res-image') 2x,
        etc...
    );
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I'm really after something that I can use today and it seems `image-set` only supports x descriptors.

Comment: @Tyssen I don't know why you're making images for different screen sizes - it seems like wasted effort. If you have text in the images (for example) then they should be positioned using CSS rather than being in the image. The whole point of CSS and responsive-styling is to prevent having to make specific new assets for different device profiles - the `srcset`/`image-set` functionality is for meaningful differences in display resolution ("resolution" meaning DPI, not pixel dimensions).

Comment: @Tyssen If you really want to go down this path, you could accomplish this goal with a simple JavaScript that executes before the page finishes loading to set a `class` attribute on the `body` element that indicates which background image should be used, e.g. `.vw320 { background-image: "320.png"; }`

Comment: @Dai I know this is old but I think you're missing one of the main reasons we might want to serve a smaller image for a smaller screen: time to finish Largest Contentful Paint. While it's technically true that a 400+DPI screen that is just 3" wide has as many pixels as the screen on my 13" laptop, the 3" wide screen is served by a mobile internet link that can be as slow as 2 Mbit while my laptop is served by multiple Gbit fibre. A 600px wide "hero" can look fine on a 3" wide screen and will load a lot faster than the 1200px needed on my laptop. This makes the x descriptor mostly useless.

Comment: In fact, the x descriptor does the opposite of what is needed to deal with slow mobile connections - it tends to be higher the smaller the device is!

Answer (score 0):

Been banging my head against this myself, and was amazed to find that in 2024 there's still no easy way to serve smaller background images for smaller screens. The background `image-set` property is definitely a step in the right direction, but since it's limited to the `x` pixel density descriptor, and lacks any knowledge of the screen's width (as provided the `<img>` `srcset` `w` descriptor), it's of no use when you want to serve a smaller image for a smaller (and presumably *slower*) device. It is also not possible to use in-line media queries in an element's `style` attribute. And using an absolutely positioned `<img>` or `<picture>` to provide a background image is awkward and hacky, and makes it more difficult to cover a box that can stretch both ways. The best I've been able to come up with is generating a `<style>` block to go along with the `<header>` that I want to give a background (code in Ruby/Rails):

```rb
def banner_background(page, widths=[1200,800], switch=900, ratio=2.33)
    banner = page.images.banner.first
    style = ""
    if banner.present?
        style += "article > header {"
        style += "background-image: url(\"#{url_for(banner.image_file.variant(resize_to_fill: [widths[0], widths[0]/ratio]))}\");"
        style += "} @media (max-width: #{switch}px) { article > header {"
        style += "background-image: url(\"#{url_for(banner.image_file.variant(resize_to_fill: [widths[1], widths[1]/ratio]))}\");"
        style += "}}"
    end
    style.html_safe
end
```

```rb
<style><%= banner_background(page) %></style>
<header>
...
```

This feels horribly kludgy, but it has have one major advantage over all other options: it works, and it cuts the download size for my header backgrounds in half - a saving of around 60 kB per image. `image-set` [support for `w` and `h` is planned](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#issue-372ac642), but until that is widely adopted we're stuck with hacks like this. Unless anyone has a better suggestion of course - which I would very much like to hear!